# Automatically rebuild Javascript Bundles on debug start

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bundle, bundling-and-minification, web-essentials

I am using Web Essentials within Visual Studio 2015 to manage bundling my JavaScript files together.

(Almost) everything is working fine.. I have my `bundleconfig.json` file in the root of my project, and when I right-click on it and choose "update bundles" it does exactly that.

The created files are exactly where I want them to be, and contain exactly what I want them to contain.

**However...**
The bundles only ever seem to get updated one of two ways:

1. I make and save a *significant* change to the `bundleconfig.json` file. (*eg: I add a new script file)*
2. I right-click on the `bundleconfig.json` file and choose "update bundles".

This is becoming quite an annoying shortfall, as if I make a small change to a single JS file, then hit F5 to start the project, the bundles wouldn't not have been rebuilt, and I won't see the change appear in the running application.

Whilst I'm aware I can simply manually rebuild the bundles before I run the project each and every time, it's quite easy to forget, then spend ages debugging a problem you've actually fixed!

I've spent ages trawling through the help for Web Essentials in vein and can't find a similar question here on SO...

Does anyone know how to force the rebuilding of the bundles each and every time I start debugging a project (perhaps on each build?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution works for me:

right-click the file "bundleconfig.json" and select enable bundle on build...

I had to do it again after adding som new js files, and now it's working again.